# Angular js: error message get displayed utill page load completes?

Tags: angularjs

I have created the simple login form and perform the validation on it but the problem is that validation is occur during the page load.My oode here.

```html
<body ng-controller="myCont">
 <form name="myForm" novalidate>
  <h2 align="center">Add The Item Here</h2> 
    <table align="center" border="2">
     <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">            
       <tr>
       <td>pid</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="pid" ng-model="user.pid" ng-maxlength="3" required="pid" ></td>
                      <td ng-show="myForm.pid.$touched  && myForm.pid.$invalid"></td>
                    <td ng-show="myForm.pid.$error.required"  style="color:red">Enter Pid</td>
                    <td ng-show="myForm.pid.$error.maxlength" style="color:red">Only 3 digits for pid</td>
                   
     </tr>
                <tr>
        <td>pname</td>
       <td><input type="text" name="pname" ng-model="user.pname" required="pname"></td>
       <td style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.pname.$touched && myForm.pname.$invalid"></td>
                    <td ng-show="myForm.pname.$error.required" style="color:red">Pname is required.</td>
                </tr>
             <tr>
     <td>pcost</td>
       <td><input type="number" name="pcost" ng-model="user.pcost" required="pcost"></td>
       <td style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.pcost.$touched && myForm.pcost.$invalid">
                    <td ng-show="myForm.pcost.$error.required" style="color:red">Pcost is required.</td>

                </tr>
                   <div ng-repeat="x in result track by $index"></div>
    <tr>
         <td>AddData<input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="addAll()">
                  </td> 
          <td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset"></td>
       </tr>  
   
</div>
</div>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp80s.png)

Comment: You'll need to give us more information to go off, we can't help you with what you've given us there.

Comment: In order to get help in this forum, you need to provide us your efforts first. A sample code would be great to start with.

Comment: two thinks: Maybe the angular doesn't initialized, try to put a single {{ anyVarName }}... if you could see the expression, angular is out. If angular is ok, take a look at ng-cloak. Verify also if the form has a name (required for validation)  and inputs has name and ng-model.

Comment: Sir,angular is properly initialized and  I am using ng-cloak at the header section but my problem is not resolve.

Answer (score 0):

try `angular-toastr` for notification of wrong credentials or error message...
Hope it will help out